# Sorting the versions in Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, sorting, aws-lambda, versioning

I wanted to sort the list of versions in AWS lambda using python. My list of versions would be like,
version = ['v1', 'v2.2', 'v2.0', 'v1.3', 'v1.2', 'v2.11', 'v1.12']

Below code works well but since pkg_resources will be deprecated so wanted to see if any alternatives available for this use case?

```
from pkg_resources import parse_version
version = ['v1', 'v2.2', 'v2.0', 'v1.3', 'v1.2', 'v2.11', 'v1.12']
sorted_version = sorted(version, key=parse_version)

sorted_version
['v1', 'v1.2', 'v1.3', 'v1.12', 'v2.0', 'v2.2', 'v2.11']
```

Tried below but not be good for my use case

- https://pypi.org/project/natsort/3.3.0/ - I cannot import this into AWS lambda directly, need to to create layer which I don't want to create it
- `distutils` is getting deprecated, so will not be able to use it

Please suggest if any alternatives which would be used for my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own function to do this, for example:

- Delete the `v`, then split by `.` and cast list items to `int`.
- Sort list values
- Join values (transformed to `str` and add the `v` again(

```py
version = ['v1', 'v2.2', 'v2.0', 'v1.3', 'v1.2', 'v2.11', 'v1.12']


def int_transform(txt):
    return [int(a) for a in txt.replace('v', "").split('.')]

sorted_version = sorted([int_transform(a) for a in version])
sorted_version = ["v" + '.'.join([str(a) for a in vers]) for vers in sorted_version]

sorted_version
# Output
['v1', 'v1.2', 'v1.3', 'v1.12', 'v2.0', 'v2.2', 'v2.11']
```